# Doctrine LAZY mode doesn't decrease queries in Symfony2

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity `Article`. Inside my entity, I have a field, `articleComment`, mappedBy a field `article` in the `ArticleComment` entity.

Here is the code :

```
class Article
{
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Project\MyBundle\Entity\ArticleComment", mappedBy="article", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $articleComment;

    // etc...
}
```

and

```
class ArticleComment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Project\MyBundle\Entity\Article", inversedBy="articleComment")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $article;

    // etc...
}
```

In a specific page, I list every articles but don't need the field articleComment. Doctrine get all the articleComment entities anyway, and I have something like 75 total queries. It's too much !

So, I just wan't to stop that behavior and get the articleComment entities ONLY if I have to use it in my page.

I tried the default parameter "`LAZY`" then "`EXTRA_LAZY`", and, finally, "`EAGER`", but nothing changes.

Do you have something in mind ?

Thanks

EDIT :

[image: DB schema]

So, here is my DB schema for the explanation.

I have a repository for my article_opinion table :

```
class ArticleOpinionRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function getList() {

        $db = $this->createQueryBuilder('ao')
                ->addSelect(array('a'))
                ->join('ao.article', 'a');

        return $db->getQuery()->getResult();
    }

}
```

Each time Doctrine get an article with that query, the article_comment attached to it is gotten too. So, one more query is executed for each.

Here is my call for the repository function, in my controller :

```
public function getListArticlesAction() {
    $articles = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('MyBundle:ArticleOpinion')->getList();

    return $this->render('MyBundle:Site:listArticle.html.twig', array('articles' => $articles));
}
```

And my twig template (for the tests) :

```
{% block body %}
    {% for a in articles %}
        {{ a.id }}<br />
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have **one and only one** comment per article, right ? If this is the case, why is `ArticleComment` differentiated from `Article` ?

Comment: That's right. Because inside my ArticleComment, I have different article categories.

Comment: If it's really a OneToOne (which I doubt as well like tchap) then simply fetch join your articleComments with your article.

Comment: In fact, I have more than just a comment inside my comment entity. That's why, I have to do it that way.

Comment: Currently you have `ArticleComment` as the owner of the association. Have you tried it the other way round, with `Article` as the owner? See [Association Mapping, One-To-One, Birectional](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional). The issue is noted in this article [Lazy-loading in OneToOne-bidirectional associations not working for inverse side](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-357)

Comment: Thanks a lot, for my one to one relation, it's working perfectly, but I want to do the same with a many to one relation. For example, an article can have readers, so, with my reader_article table, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suppose you correctly want `OneToOne` in your schema; You could use the hint `HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD` to avoid lazy-loading `OneToOne` entities :

```
$qb->getQuery()->setHint(Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true);
```

> NB : But then you won't even get the `id` of your `ArticleComment` in case you need it, because it won't be joined... so be extra careful

**EDIT** : You can try to hydrate as an array, too, to force lazy loading :

```
$query = $queryBuilder->getQuery();
$query->getResult(Query:HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: I'm trying that solution, I give you a feed back in a few seconds

Comment: I still have my 75 queries... The fact is that I have a getList function in my ArticleRepository which have a lot of parameters. At the end, I just do my `return $db->getQuery()->getResult();`. So I tried `$db->getQuery()->setHint(Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true);` just before

Comment: I suspect that your 75 queries are not really related to comments but maybe status and customer ? I edited my post with another solution that you may want to try

Comment: Let's forget my repository one second, it will be maybe more easier to solve. I do a `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager->getRepository('MyBundle:Article')->find(5);` and Doctrine get all the articleComment even if I don't want it. In fact, just want my entity without extra entities.

Comment: I think your 75 queries problem is a result of doctrine lazy loading after some kind of `foreach()` statement, so you might want to try the other way round : loading eagerly to get everything in one query. But if you really only want your entity, I guess the only solution is native SQL with `SELECT * From Article;`

Comment: Thank you but don't want to use native SQL. Take a look in my post EDIT with the DB schema

Answer (score 0):

I´m pretty sure that the question isn´t about how you are mapping entities, but about how you use data.

I think lazy mode works but somehow in a some not obvious way application is accessing $article->article_comment and because of that a query is performing.

Try to cut out (to comment) different parts of your application (may be twig template?) and find out where you are accessing these data.

BTW Extra Lazy mode has no sense at one-to-one relationship.

UPD:
Seems like at One-To-One relationship Doctrine decides that it's must load whole entity which consists of two objects.

To avoid this behaviour you have to hint that partial load is OK

```
$query = $db->getQuery()->setHint(Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true)->getResult();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just have the little repository function that I posted earlier. After, I have all the results in an array. I do a foreach to list all the articles, but, at this moment, every article_comment is load.

Comment: Please show how you're calling the repository function and how it is rendered in template

Comment: I just edited my post with your request @Dmitry Malyshenko

Comment: I just realized that what you've drawn about your DB scheme doesn't correspond with the code. In your scheme article_comment's id is stored in 'articles' table. But mapping is done like if article's id is stored in 'article_comments' table. 
Doesn't your Symfony's profiler show any mapping's errors?

Comment: I found out the issue. Please see update to my answer

Comment: Indeed @Dmitry, I inversed the columns in my DB schema but the good part is the code. Still looking for the answer...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you mean. I've implemented your relationship and called a query as I've pointed, with Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD. Everything was loaded by 1 SQL query